# How to apply a function for every row in data?

Tags: r

My data:

```
> dput(head(tbl))
structure(c("a2p1u8", "a2qab2", "a6zl23", "a6zlf3", "a6zq61", 
"a6ztx1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0.9339597", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "14.2445924", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", " 1.84391660", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "1.00000000", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0.85034470", 
"0", "0.06312408", "0", "0", "1.11684073", "1.00000000", "1.29478436", 
"0.135377134", "0", "0", "0.941579636", "0.389199799", "0.705215641", 
"0.34063483", "0", "0", "1.00000000", "0.46785766", "0", "1.43325438", 
"0", "0", "0", "0.15782118", "0", "1.71425096", "0", "0", "0", 
"0.38274080", "0", " 0.71553232", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "1.72759758", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1.712898580", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0.74788829", "1.00000000", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1.29452015", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0.85273992", "0", "0", "0"), .Dim = c(6L, 25L
), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Gene name", "2_1", "2_2", "2_3", 
"2_4", "2_5", "2_6", "2_7", "2_8", "2_9", "2_10", "2_11", "2_12", 
"2_13", "2_14", "2_15", "2_16", "2_17", "2_18", "2_19", "2_20", 
"2_21", "2_22", "2_23", "2_24")))
```

As an output I want to get a new data.frame/matrix with the same number of rows and columns and with the number 1 in the cells which this function finds a peak.

```
which(diff(sign(diff(Gene name)))==-2)+1
```

How to find a peak in each row of data.frame ?

Comment: What do you mean by "finds a peak"? The structure you have provided corresponds to a character matrix. You probably want all but the first column as `numeric`, so a good start would be to coerce to a data frame and change the data type: `tbl.df <- as.data.frame(tbl, stringsAsFactors=FALSE); tbl.df[, -1] <- apply(tbl.df[, -1], 2, as.numeric)`.

Comment: This is a function which I want to use (it is used for "finding peaks"): `which(diff(sign(diff(Gene name - name of the row)))==-2)+1`

Comment: Still don't see what you mean by "find peaks." Trying to infer from your comment, since "Gene name" is a string (from which a numerical value cannot be easily inferred), and "name of the row" is not defined but defaults to the integers 1 through 6. Perhaps you could walk us through the calculation, if not in R code, then in human-readable math? For example, if you are treating each row as a separate sequence and "peak" is the same as "max", then perhaps the peak for "a2p1u8" would be column 2_15 (value of 1.727598).

Comment: I believe the OP wants to apply the function (which returns indices of 'peaks') to each row of the data.

Comment: Perhaps one of the following gives what you want/need `apply(tbl.df[,-1], 1, function(rr) max(rr))`, `apply(tbl.df[,-1], 1, function(rr) which.max(rr))`, or `colnames(tbl.df)[1+apply(tbl.df[,-1], 1, function(rr) which.max(rr))]`.

Comment: I am half guessing here, but I think @ShaxiLiver's definition of "peak" here is not simply the row max, but rather is defined as elements to the right of those that return `TRUE` for `diff(sign(diff(Gene name)))==-2`. It seems there can be multiple "peaks" per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is probably easiest with a numeric matrix, so we'll take the gene names and store them to use as row names, and we'll remove the gene column. We'll then add the row names and coerce the matrix to numeric (this last step should be done column by column, i.e. `apply`ing the `as.numeric` function over the 2nd dimension.

```
nm <- tbl[, 1]
tbl <- apply(tbl[, -1], 2, as.numeric)
row.names(tbl) <- nm
```

Now we can create a binary indicator matrix that shows whether `diff(sign(diff(x)))` is equal to `-2`. We do this by applying your function (slightly modified, removing the `which` call to ensure it returns a matrix of the desired dimensions) to the first dimension (rows) of `tbl`.

```
minus2 <- t(apply(tbl, 1, function(x) as.numeric(diff(sign(diff(x)))==-2)))
```

We want the columns to the right of those that were `-2`, so we can `cbind` a column of zeroes to the left `minus2`.

```
peaks <- cbind(0, minus2)
```

This produces:

```
peaks

#        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23]
# a2p1u8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# a2qab2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
# a6zl23    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
# a6zlf3    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# a6zq61    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# a6ztx1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: I noticed that my output has 23 columns, where the input has 24. This is due to the two `diff` calls, each of which shortens the vector by one. Not sure where that extra column belongs.

Comment: Do you have any idea what can we do to get this 24th column back to my data ?

Comment: One more comment:. I already noticed that we just added a column of 0s to the left but it should be like that. Sometimes there might be a higher number in first column than in second one so that means there is a peak. Do you know how to do it properly ? Maybe my assumption to use such function wasn't correct.

Comment: I added the column of zeroes to the left because your function returns indices of cells to the right of cells for which the function is equal to `-2`. Unless I've misinterpreted something, this means that there can't be any `1`'s in the leftmost column.

Comment: "Do you have any idea what can we do to get this 24th column back to my data?" - I can't really answer this for you, because you've designed a function that drops data... maybe you need to rethink your function.

Comment: That's true. It was my function but I already noticed it's not a correct one. I will propably create another "question" to ask how I should find my "peaks".

Comment: If you do so, make sure you are very clear about what you mean by "peaks". Give a small example data set as well as the expected output.

Comment: Will do it. Thanks for your help!